# function name is undefined in python class

Tags: python, nameerror

I am relatively new to python and i am experiencing some issues with namespacing.

```
class a:
    def abc(self):
        print "haha" 
    def test(self):
        abc()

b = a()
b.test() #throws an error of abc is not defined. cannot explain why is this so
```

Comment: It is working, the function `abc()` of `class a` is called by its instance.

Comment: I think instead of `b.abc()`, yours call to `b.test()` should be throwing the error. And that's because you should be calling `abc()` with the reference of the class instance. Simply replace `abc()` with `self.abc()` in `test()` function of `class a`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since `test()` doesn't know who is `abc`, that msg `NameError: global name 'abc' is not defined` you see should happen when you invoke `b.test()` (calling `b.abc()` is fine), change it to:

```
class a:
    def abc(self):
        print "haha" 
    def test(self):
        self.abc()  
        # abc()

b = a()
b.abc() #  'haha' is printed
b.test() # 'haha' is printed
```

Answer (score 29):

In order to call method from the same class, you need the `self` keyword.

```
class a:
    def abc(self):
        print "haha" 
    def test(self):
        self.abc() // will look for abc method in 'a' class
```

Without the `self` keyword, python is looking for the `abc` method in the global scope, that is why you are getting this error.