# Trying to use the return value from one function in another but getting undefined variable instead

Tags: python, undefined-variable

I have this code:

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self,name=""):
        self.name = name 
        self.kind = "Unknown"
        self.toys = []  
    def add_toys(self,toys):
        new_list = []
        for toy in self.toys:
            if toy not in new_list:
                new_list.append(toy)   
        return new_list
    def __str__(self):
        toys_list = add_toys(self,toys)  
        if self.toys == []:
            return "{} is a {} that has no toys".format(self.name,self.kind)
        else:
            return "{} is a {} that has the following toys: {}".format(self.name,self.kind,toys_list)
```

In the function `add_toys()` I have the return value *new_list*.
I want to use that return value in the function `__ str__` and define it as `toys_list`.
However, when I write `toys_list = add_toys(self, toys)` it says that:

> `add_toys` is an **undefined** variable

Comment: I am not fully sure what you are trying to achieve, but for the error where you say "it says that add_toys is an undefined variable.", I believe you need `self.add_toys`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function name is undefined in python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805028/function-name-is-undefined-in-python-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `add_toys` method isn't good, you're not using the `toys` parameters and it shouldn't return anything, it should be like

```
class Pet:
    # __init__ is OK

    def add_toys(self, *toys):
        for toy in toys:
            if toy not in self.toys:
                self.toys.append(toy)

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.toys:
            return "{} is a {} that has no toys".format(self.name, self.kind)
        else:
            return "{} is a {} that has the following toys: {}".format(self.name, self.kind, self.toys)
```

Use like

```
p = Pet("Foo")
p.add_toys("ball")
p.add_toys("plate", "frisbee")
print(p) # Foo is a Unknown that has the following toys: ['ball', 'plate', 'frisbee']
```

---

You could use directly a `set`

```
class Pet:

    def __init__(self, name, kind="Unknown"):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind
        self.toys = set()

    def add_toys(self, *toys):
        self.toys.update(toys)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing in add_toys you are accesing toys variable from the class level variable, so remove that argument and the second is `add_toys(self,toys)` is not correct syntax, you will need to use it like `self.add_toys()`

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self,name=""):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = "Unknown"
        self.toys = []
    
    def add_toys(self):
        new_list = []
        for toy in self.toys:
            if toy not in new_list:
                new_list.append(toy)
        return new_list
    
    def __str__(self):
        toys_list = self.add_toys()
        if self.toys == []:
            return "{} is a {} that has no toys".format(self.name, self.kind)
        else:
            return "{} is a {} that has the following toys: {}".format(self.name, self.kind, toys_list)
```

### Alternative:

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self,name=""):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = "Unknown"
        self.toys = []
    
    def add_toys(self, toys):
        new_list = []
        for toy in toys:
            if toy not in new_list:
                new_list.append(toy)
        return new_list
    
    def __str__(self):
        toys_list = self.add_toys(self.toys)
        if self.toys == []:
            return "{} is a {} that has no toys".format(self.name, self.kind)
        else:
            return "{} is a {} that has the following toys: {}".format(self.name, self.kind, toys_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is the undefined *function*. A referencing **self** (needed for each class member, field or method) was missing:
`toys_list = self.add_toys()`.

#### Reconsider design

Why have the collection of *toys* managed twice?
(a) as field `toys` wich can have duplicates,
(b) as return from `add_toys` which will hide duplicates and ensures unique elements.

You will have to maintain both in sync. They differ in their capabilities and should be applied to different use-cases.

#### Assumption: unique toys

I would also go with a **set** as type for the field `toys` directly. Because this way you can reuse an existing *data structure* which **guarantees the uniqueness** you have implemented explicitly in `add_toys`. Additionally the add/update function is convenient to modify the collection.

#### Improve: string building

Furthermore your string function can be refactored:

```py
def __str__(self):
    subject = "{} is a {}".format(self.name, self.kind)
    hasToys = "has no toys" if not self.toys else "has the following toys: {}".format(self.toys)
    return "{subject} that {hasToys}".format (subject, hasToys)
```

it uses a **ternary operator** instead of the if statement; with referencing (via `self`!) new `set` field directly: `self.toys`
Plus a 3 step building to allow the **single return** as clearly visible expectation at the end.

Answer (score -1):

you can't call class method directly, you must call it using self.

like this ..

```
self.toys_list= self.add_toys(self, toys)
```

Comment: Can't we omitt the first argument `self` when inside the class: `self.add_toys( toys )` ?

Comment: yes, we can omitt that first argument ` self` ,  but i am talking about that `self.` which comes before method name, any method or variable under a class can't call directly, it leads to undefined error. we must have to call it using `self.`  like `self.method_name()` and `self.variable_name` ..